# javascript eager assignment

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Influenced by jQuery, I'm experimenting with method chaining in javascript. I constructed a wrapper around an array which will accept coordinate points and transform methods. It's general syntax is something like:

```
myPath = new Path().move({x:50,y:50}).line({x:20,y:20}).rotate(Math.PI/3);
```

it works well, and it makes it somewhat more readable than a string of coordinates. However now I want to be able to duplicate the existing path by doing a concatenation of
its reversed self:

```
// create a symmetrical path.
myPath = new Path().move().line().etc().etc.concat(myPath.reverse());
```

But that fails because myPath is unknown as argument to concat. It works when i do:

```
var myPath = new Path();
myPath.move().line().etc().etc().concat(myPath.reverse());
```

But I'm wondering is there a construct other and shorter than above to immediately assign the new Object to the variable definition?
If its not possible in Javascript, i'd be interested if it's possible in other languages?

regards,
Jeroen.

Comment: You could define the `concat` method so that it allows string parameters. For instance, `.concat('reverse')`.

Comment: I dislike the code `var myPath = new Path(); myPath.move().line().etc().etc().concat(myPath.reverse());`. Its ugliness lies in the fact that its result depends on the evaluation order, namely on which of `myPath.move().line().etc().etc()` and `myPath.reverse()` is evaluated earlier. Depending on this, you either get the path duplicated, or you get concatenated (the reverse of) the empty path. I assume that the specification defines which is correct, but for a human reader the code is ambiguous hence evil.

Comment: By the way, do myPath.move(), .reverse(), .etc(), modify the myPath itself, or do they return its modified copy?

Comment: @xofon Thank you for your feedback, I'll start counting the positive and negative reactions on this approach 1:1 now (+1 being my boss :-). Method chaining evaluates code left to right, basically the same direction my intended audience reads. All methods do return the modified self (imperative). Some methods however do also accept path as argument and in that case a modified copy is returned.

Comment: I understand that the order of the chained methods is neccessarily left to right, and as concerns this I am also +1. My doubt is when the methods' arguments are evaluated. I mean, there is neccessarily some right-to-left-ness in the code, namely reverse() obviously has to be calculated before concat() is invoked, and what is ambiguous is when is move() invoked.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is the role of .reverse(). In particular, if the semantics is `tmpPath = new Path().move().line().etc(); newPath = tmpPath.concat(tmpPath.reverse());` you get the reversed tmpPath concatenated upon the _reversed_ tmpPath, don't you?

Comment: @xofon i stand corrected the way this should have been written is `...etc().concat(tmpPath.reverse(tmpPath))` (passing in argument returns a deep copy), I'm still trying to find out how to make this as logical and readable as possible, and doing quick code snippets like here on SO is probably a good testcase, that is not very intuitive yet. You can see the code alive on www.iscriptdesign.com -> iPath, and the code itself is at www.iscriptdesign.com/iPath.jsvg. I do appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Path.prototype.concat = function () {
    this.concatting = true;
    return this;    
};

Path.prototype.reverse = function () {
    if (this.concatting) {
        Array.push.apply(
            this.pathArr,
            Array.slice(this.pathAr).reverse()
        );
        this.concatting = false;
    } else {
        this.pathAr.reverse();
    }

    return this;
};

var myPath = new Path().move().line().etc().concat().reverse();
```

Not very elegant, but here you go.

> But I'm wondering is there a construct
>   other and shorter than above to
>   immediately assign the new Object to
>   the variable definition?

No, you can't reference what hasn't been created yet.

---

You could do this as well:

```
(myPath = new Path()).move().line().etc().etc.concat(myPath.reverse());
```

Comment: Thanks for ideas and the `(myPath = new Path())` I'm going to investigate!

Answer (score 1):

You might code a `duplicate` method along the lines of

```
Path.prototype.duplicate = function () {
    var clone = this.clone().reverse();
    this.concat(clone);
    return this;
}
```

and then call `var myPath = new Path().move().line().etc().duplicate().